# MYSQL query display quantity of product from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

product :

```
id_product  | product_name      | price

560         | AAA               | 1500 
561         | BBB               | 1750
```

attr :

```
id_attr | id_product | size | qty

100     | 560        | S    | 11

100     | 560        | M    | 9

100     | 560        | L    | 7

100     | 560        | XL   | 21
```

How to display

```
product_name | qty_S | qty_M | qty_L | qty_XL | qty_total | price

AAA          | 11    | 9     | 7     | 21     | 48        | 1500

BBB          | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0         | 1750
```

i try to make query like this :

```
select p.*, a.*,

sum(a.qty) as qty_total,

[how_to_display_query] as qty_S,

[how_to_display_query] as qty_M,

[how_to_display_query] as qty_L,

[how_to_display_query] as qty_XL,


FROM product p LEFT JOIN attr a
ON p.id_product = a.id_product
group by p.id_product;
```

===============================================

Please help me, sorry for bad english... Thanks

Comment: `sum(case when size = 'S' then qty end) as qty_S`

Comment: Seems like a good solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to pivot the results.. but you cant pivot in mysql as it doesn't have that functionality.. so you need to "fake" a pivot by using an aggregate and a conditional statement

the way to do that is like this.. `MAX(CASE... ) SUM(CASE... )` etc.. can also be done with if `MAX(IF... ) SUM(IF... )`.

```
SELECT p.product_name
    SUM(a.qty) as qty_total,
    MAX(CASE size WHEN 'S' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as qty_S,
    MAX(CASE size WHEN 'M' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as qty_M,
    MAX(CASE size WHEN 'L' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as qty_L,
    MAX(CASE size WHEN 'XL' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as qty_XL,
    p.price
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN attr a ON p.id_product = a.id_product
GROUP BY by p.id_product;
```

i used MAX() here because you only seem to be getting one number.. if you were wanting to add multiple quantities then you can change MAX to SUM